# Getting a KeyHash

Tags: android

I can't get keyhash, it shows this System error.How can I fix this
`W/System.err: android.content.pm.PackageManager$NameNotFoundException:`

Here is my code

```
PackageInfo info;
    try {
         info = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(
                 "com.example.yunus.quetosviewpager",
                 PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES);
         for (Signature signature : info.signatures) {
             MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA");
             md.update(signature.toByteArray());
             Log.d(TAG, Base64.encodeToString(md.digest(), Base64.DEFAULT));
         }
     } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
     } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

Please double check if your packagename is spelt correctly. Also, an app with that package name that is written inside of

```
getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(
             "com.example.yunus.quetosviewpager",
             PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES);
```

should be installed on the device where you are running those lines, just in case you have a separate app for obtaining SHA.